# Проблема с Pynput

Tags: python, if, клавиатура, key, pynput

Здраствуйте, возникла проблема с использованием pynput в программе. Я очень долго работал над решением этой проблемы, но мне так и не удалось это сделать. Я не понимаю или это моя ошибка, или ошибка создателей python, pynput? Может я чего-то не знаю или не понимаю?
Максимум того, что удалось сделать - программа работает, но не выполняет все задуманные функции.

Суть проблемы такова:
Мне нужно создать программу, которая:
Если пользователь нажмет клавишу ~Alt~, выполняет первое задуманное действие.
А если пользователь снова нажмет клавишу ~Alt~, то программа выполнит второе задуманное действие, но это должно произойти только тогда, если перед этим пользователь уже хотя бы раз нажал на клавишу ~Alt~ и никак иначе.

То бишь:

```
if пользователь нажал клавишу ~Alt~ впервые:
     print ("~Что-то~")
if пользователь нажал клавишу ~Alt~ еще раз:
     print ("~Что-то другое~")
```

---

Звучит вроде просто, но в реализации совсем не так.
Вот моя (не полностью рабочая) программа:

```
from pynput import keyboard

alt_is_pressed = False
def on_press(key):
   if key == keyboard.Key.alt_l and alt_is_pressed == False:
      print("Эта функция работает")
      alt_is_pressed = True
   if key == keyboard.Key.alt_l and alt_is_pressed == True:
      print("УРА! Наконец-то оно работает")

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Ну если запустить эту программу, то видно, что она работает не так как следует.
Насколько я понял это связано с тем, что каждый раз когда функция выполняется то значение переменной перезаписывается, а нужно что-бы её значение изменилось только один раз.

Ну если кто-то знает как исправить мою программу или знает другой робочий способ решения этой задачи, то буду очень рад помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю что ваш код должен быть примерно таким:

```
alt_is_pressed = False
def on_press(key):
   global alt_is_pressed
   if key == keyboard.Key.alt_l and alt_is_pressed == False:
      print("Эта функция работает")
      alt_is_pressed = True
   elif key == keyboard.Key.alt_l and alt_is_pressed == True:
      print("УРА! Наконец-то оно работает")
      alt_is_pressed = False
```